# Python how to decode code from GPS to NMEA?

Tags: python, gps, hex

I am trying to program a GPS (I have a GPS "here2" + CubeOrange + Raspberry PI 4 Model B).

From the circuit I get this result:

`b'3DA\x95F\xaa?p%b=,XIB\n'

3344470000000000000000cf19c93f0a

b'3DT\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n'

334441f959aa3f31895f3df15749420a

b'3DG\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xcf\x19\xc9?\n'

33445400000000000a

b'3DA\xa0_\xaa?T\xb7]=\xa4WIB\n'

3344470000000000000000cf19c93f0a`
...

I have a question - what format is this `b'3DA\x95F\xaa?p%b=,XIB\n'` (I can't find information anywhere on the internet)

I converted it to hex `3344470000000000000000cf19c93f0a` but I don't know if it's right. I need in decimal to have information about speed, altitude, position (above is just a code snippet). I made it hex but in my opinion it is wrong.

'b'3.. - is the headline,
\n-newline character,
the rest I do not understand..

Thank you for your help.

I searched for information on the Internet but did not find an answer.

Comment: You should check the documentation of GPS (maybe just the chip of GPS). Your data is not NMEA. Possibly you can set the GPS to send you text data. Your data is just binary data. Note: we have also a sister site about Raspberry Pi (and also one for Arduino and CO). Maybe such site may be more relevant: check links on top right icon (and check if the question fit in there).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the data is packed info byte-array to unpack data use the Python struct library

```py
>>> import struct
>>> data = b'3DA\x95F\xaa?p%b=,XIB\n'
>>> struct.unpack("ffff",data)
(-3.902983930259824e-26, 2.372699393234608e+29, 2.6912996570899184e-12, 9.354554656484993e-33)
>>>
```